# Is the rank a well defined notion for free objects?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

In other words, if $X$ and $Y$ are bijective sets, is it true that $F_X$ is isomorphic to $F_Y$, where $F_X$ denotes the free object on $X$ in a category with free objects? If not, what about if $X$ and $Y$ are finite sets?

Comment: I want to remark that if $X \mapsto F_X$ is functorial then $X \cong Y$ implies $F_X \cong F_Y$. This holds for all functors, so your notion of rank is off. Try rethinking this. Additionally, I suggest you try to formalize what you mean by a free object. Can you prove that ranks exist in some special cases, say abelian groups or vector spaces?

Comment: Ah I see. I'm wondering now why my notion of rank is off though? I wanted to have a name for the cardinality of a basis for an arbitrary free object, so I didn't have to define it separately for free groups, free abelian groups, modules, etc. Would I be wrong to do this?

Comment: You're certainly on the right track, but a so called "basis" will not always work as they do for vector spaces. But those are a great source of motivation. To try and define rank, try and recall how you define and proved well definition of dimension of vector spaces. In this case, the free functor takes $X$ to the vector space on basis $X$. Is there a relevant property this functor satisfies?

Comment: From the title of your question, I expected the question to be something like: "In other words, if $F_X$ is isomorphic to $F_Y$, is it true that $X$ and $Y$ are bijective sets?" Are you sure that's not what you wanted to ask?

Comment: Hmm, I know that the converse of what I have asked is not always true, e.g., in the category of rings, there are examples of isomorphic rings which do not have the same rank. However, for a notational convenience, if I were to define rank(F_X)=|X| for an arbitrary free object, and say that all finitely generated free objects in a category are classified by their rank, this would not be wrong would it? I would of course remark that this notion of rank doesn't always behave the way we would like and would show the cases where it does, so as to not cause confusion.

Comment: @bof Ah yes, I realise now that the way I stated the question is a bit confusing. I was already aware that the converse is false in general, so I wanted to see if this direction was true. If not, I would say that rank is not 'well defined' because neither direction holds. If at least one direction holds, then there is an argument that it is worth defining for general free groups in a category. That is what I meant.

Answer (score 3):

Free objects are functorial, meaning there is an adjunction $F\dashv U$ between the category of sets and a category of algebraic objects, with $F$ the free object functor and $U$ the underlying set functor. So $F$ necessarily preserves isomorphisms by functoriality.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your response.